# Display message with my user id - it will not present it

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

Right now I am working to create a messaging system to the website, but when I have to pull at it is sent to me and from me, it will not display content on the page.

there mind if I say that it should only take one of them, so accepterer it is perfectly fine.

It's making error here

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult besked(int id)
{
    DataLinqDB db = new DataLinqDB();
    UnderviserViewModel Model = new UnderviserViewModel();

    //Brugerid :)
    int userid = Helper.BrugerInformation.SessionVale.SessionBrugerid();

    //Det som er blevet sendt til mig!
    var ViewBeskederFrom = db.MessageTeachers.Where(i => i.id == id && i.fk_userTo == userid || i.fk_userFrom == userid).ToList();
    if (ViewBeskederFrom != null)
    {
        Model.BeskederFrom = ViewBeskederFrom.ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Indbakke");
    }

    return View(Model);
}
```

It works fine if I do it like this.

```
var ViewBeskederFrom = db.MessageTeachers.Where(i => i.id == id && i.fk_userTo == userid || i.fk_userFrom == userid).ToList();
```

How can it be that it will not present it if I'm sender or recipient of the message end?

Database here (i have 316 userid)
[image]

**UPDATE**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult besked(int id)
{
    DataLinqDB db = new DataLinqDB();
    UnderviserViewModel Model = new UnderviserViewModel();

    //Brugerid :)
    int userid = Helper.BrugerInformation.SessionVale.SessionBrugerid();

    //Det som er blevet sendt til mig!
    var ViewBeskederFrom = db.MessageTeachers.FirstOrDefault(i => i.id == id);
    if (ViewBeskederFrom != null)
    {
        List<MessageTeacher> list = db.MessageTeachers.Where(i => i.id == id && i.fk_userTo == userid || i.fk_userFrom == userid).ToList();
        if (list != null)
        {
            Model.BeskederFrom = list.ToList();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Indbakke");
    }

    return View(Model);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you have records matching all 3 conditions ?

Comment: @Shyju I just refresh content with both image and all httpget when I come in on the single page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have an **AND** condition

```
 i.fk_userTo == userid && i.fk_userFrom == userid
```

That means you need to have records with both `fk_userTo` and `fk_userFrom` column having the same `userId` value. From your screenshot you do not have such records.

You should be doing the **OR** condition which will give you either messages you sent or messages sent to you by some other user

```
i.fk_userTo == userid || i.fk_userFrom == userid
```

Also, your first if condition( checking the record `id` value against the `id` parameter of the action method) is probably going to give you only one record assuming id is the primary key of the table. So the result you are getting in `ViewBeskederFrom` variable will be List with maximum of one record.

Comment: Okay, I've tried to update code as you can see here but while making it still as shown in the figure below. I just made an update call code.

Comment: So what is not working now ? Are you not getting data from your LINQ expression call ?

Comment: I think you misunderstand me, I could well imagine that the utrækker conversation that I have with the other users, I have to have the conversation with userid 17741 and 316 - it's all together.

Comment: Ohh now its work for me. Thanks for help. I used the code you wrote, I'd just add something next that I had forgotten.